# How do you stop an FTP Service resetting?

Tags: ftp

While using an FTP service through the command line, I try to retrieve a directory listing.
I get:

```
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list.
> ftp: get :Connection reset by peer
```

Any ideas how I should go about resolving this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling Passive FTP on your client. You can read more about the active/passive ftp
[here](https://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)

> *In active mode FTP the client connects from a random unprivileged
>   port (N > 1023) to the FTP server's
>   command port, port 21. Then, the
>   client starts listening to port N+1
>   and sends the FTP command PORT N+1 to
>   the FTP server. The server will then
>   connect back to the client's specified
>   data port from its local data port,
>   which is port 20.*

[image]

> *In passive mode FTP the client initiates both connections to the
>   server, solving the problem of
>   firewalls filtering the incoming data
>   port connection to the client from the
>   server.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its dropping you because it cannot open a connection over the data transmission ports. Is the FTP server within your LAN?

Comment: yes - it is within the LAN